# Unpivot or Something else

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns that should only contain one value but some entries contains 2 or 3 values . all the other columns are the same for these problem rows .

```
Table A - Currently 
Deal ID | PA ID | other columns 
1         2       xxxxx
1,2       2       xxxxx
3         1,5     xxxxx
```

What I want

```
Deal ID | PA ID | other columns 
1         2       xxxxx
1         2       xxxxx
2         2       xxxxx
3         1       xxxxx
3         5       xxxxx
```

Not sure how to do this ? Think I need to `UNPIVOT` and then remove the ,.

Comment: My version of DB2 doesn't have `UNPIVOT`, so I'd write a recursive query (not able to now) to split this.  But that layout... please spindle, fold, and mutilate the original designer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.  It is brute force and uses union all to bring get multiple copies:

```
with incols as (
     select (case when charindex(Dealid, ',') > 0
                  then left(DealId, charindex(Dealid, ',') - 1)
                  else DealId
             end) as DealId1,
            (case when charindex(Dealid, ',') > 0
                  then substring(DealId, charindex(DealId, ',') + 1, 100)
             end) as DealId2,
            (case when charindex(PAId, ',') > 0
                  then left(PAId, charindex(PAId, ',') - 1)
                  else PAId
             end) as PAId1,
            (case when charindex(PAId, ',') > 0
                  then substring(PAId, charindex(PAId, ',') + 1, 100)
             end) as PAId2,
            t.*
     from t
    ),
    deals as (
     select (case when whichdeal = 1 then deal1 else deal2 end) as newdeal, t.*
     from ((select *, 1 as whichdeal
            from t
           ) union all
           (select *, 2 as whichdeal
            from t
            where deal2 is not null
           ))  t
    )
select newdeal as dealid, t.*
from deals
```

Including PAs requires adding another CTE, and then joining deals and PAs on dealid and PA id to get all possible combinations.  You didn't specify exactly what you want to happen when there are duplicates in both rows, so I'm just guessing that you would want all combinations.

Comment: I getting an error Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: I left an argument out of the charindex.  I just fixed it.

Comment: Okay, finally executed your query . unfortuantley it does not work . It gives me a new deal coulm that has the 2 values for deal id in it . Basically you are justing 5 columns to the table. Think it is not splitting it into the seperate rows based on Deal id or PA id . Thanks for the try anyway as it is a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( 
  DealID VARCHAR(10), 
  PAID   VARCHAR(200), 
  [DESC] VARCHAR(100)) 

INSERT @t 
SELECT '1', 
       '2', 
       'xxxx' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '1,2', 
       '2', 
       'xxxx' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '3', 
       '1,5', 
       'xxxx' 

SELECT LEFT(b, Charindex(',', b + ',') - 1) AS DealID, 
       LEFT(d, Charindex(',', d + ',') - 1) AS PAID, 
       [Desc] 
FROM   (SELECT Substring(DealID, DE.number, 200) AS b, 
               Substring(PAID, PA.number, 200)   AS d, 
               [Desc] 
        FROM   @t DealID 
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT number 
                          FROM   master.dbo.spt_values 
                          WHERE  number BETWEEN 1 AND 200) PA 
                 ON Substring(',' + PAID, PA.number, 1) = ',' 
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT number 
                          FROM   master.dbo.spt_values S 
                          WHERE  number BETWEEN 1 AND 200) DE 
                 ON Substring(',' + DealID, DE.number, 1) = ',') t
```